# How do i remesh a Circle?

Tags: modeling, remesh

I am trying to find a good solution for remeshing a circular faces...
Is there something obvious i am missing ? I want the circle to be made out of quads, like if you would subdivide a plane...
thanks in advance

Comment: Hello, could you please show your current mesh?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use grid fill, to get a circle mesh filled with quads:

[image]

here is how you make a circle in a grid and then you can delete the inner vertices and do grid fill:

[image]

for this you need to enable the LoopTools add-on (which is delivered with Blender)

Comment: thanks, super helpfull

Comment: you are welcome!